# Проверка данных на ввод

Tags: java, android

Господа, подскажите, только только начинаю разбираться.
Мне нужно сделать примерно следующие вещи:
1) Имеется строка для ввода данных, мы пишем, к примеру, число 5 и всплывает сообщение "правильно" или "не правильно".
Как сделать такую проверку на ввод?
*как на первом фото
2) Как вывести строку "Правильно" так же сбоку? (она, как бэ, выезжает :DD)
А не просто всплывающим сообщением?
*как на втором фото[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы только начали использовать SoloLearn для изучения языка, и уже хотите такие штуки писать - то вы явно поспешили. Изучите, сначала, основы языка. =_=

Comment: в общих вопросах по разработке не нужно указывать используемую вами IDE, это никак не влияет на ответ. IDE указывается только в вопросах с проблемами работы самой IDE, а не того, что вы в ней делаете.  Так же один вопрос должен содержать только одну проблему, если у вас несколько проблем, задайте несколько вопросов

Answer (score 1):

1) Сравниваем текст, введенный в editText и строку, например "5".

```
if (editText.getText().toString().equals("5")) {
//Тут код, который выполнится, если строки равны
} else {
//Тут, если не равны
}
```

Со вторым посложнее, нужно создавать View с текстом и анимировать его появление